# How to prevent get accessor to call set accessor when assigning a property

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, properties, get

Applies to: .Net, C#, .Net core

### Issue Description:

This might be an Edgecase or I am doing something completely wrong.
I am following the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) in order to create a class with properties.
The Class should provide an interface to active directory.

When I call the get accessor, the property might not have been set yet within my program and therefore the property should be pulled from active directory, set to the class and be returned.

In order to save resources, I only want to pull the property if it has not been set yet.
The issue is that the Get Accessor calls the Set Accessor in order to set the property in my program.
The Set accessor in itself then tries to push the "new" value back to active directory, eventhough I want to have a Readonly operation from active directory.

### Reproducible code:

This is how one example of such a property looks like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// sAMAccountName - the logon name. eg. "musterma1"
/// </summary>
public string LogonName
{
    get
    {
        // if the value is not set,pull it from active directory
        LogonName ??= GetProperty("sAMAccountName");// if null, pull value;
        return LogonName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != LogonName)
        {
            // if the value has changed, push it to active directory
            LogonName = value;
            SetProperty("sAMAccountName", LogonName);
        }
    }
}
// further properties here

/// <summary>
/// this function calls the corresponsing active directory function in order 
/// to populate a poperty of the given user
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">which property to populate</param>
/// <param name="value">what value should the property have?</param>
private void SetProperty(string property, string value)
{
    ObjectProperties.SetProperty(property, value, this.DistinguishedName);
}
/// <summary>
/// this function calls the corresponsing active directory function in order 
/// to receive the current users property
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">which property to poulate</param>
private string GetProperty(string property)
{
    return ObjectProperties.AttributeValuesSingleString("property", this.DistinguishedName);
}
```

I thought about checking for null first and if the property is currently null, then only set it in the program, don't push it to active directory. But then, what about assigning new properties? The values will not get pushed:

```cs
set
{
    if (LogonName == null) LogonName = value;
    else if (value != LogonName)
    {
        // if the value has changed, push it to active directory
        LogonName = value;
        SetProperty("sAMAccountName", LogonName);
    }
}
```

### Question:

Do you know how to call the get accessor and set the property in my program without calling the set accessor and immediately push the property back into active directory?

Comment: give your property `LogonName` a backing value `logonName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create private field named i.e. `_logonName` and rewrite your Get\Set using it. For example:

```cs
private string _logonName;

public string LogonName
{
    get
    {
        // if the value is not set,pull it from active directory
        _logonName ??= GetProperty("sAMAccountName");// if null, pull value;
        return _logonName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _logonName)
        {
            // if the value has changed, push it to active directory
            _logonName = value;
            SetProperty("sAMAccountName", _logonName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -.- Thank you a lot. Sometimes you cant see the forest by all the trees we say in germany

Comment: @julianbechtold Bitte schön. Viel Glück

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend not checking the value is different before setting. The code using your code can do this and it makes sense that calling a Set accessor will always set something.

I would rewrite it as below

```
public string LogonName
{
    get
    {
        // if the value is not set,pull it from active directory
        LogonName ??= GetProperty("sAMAccountName");// if null, pull value;
        return LogonName;
    }
    set
    {
            // if the value has changed, push it to active directory
            LogonName = value;
            SetProperty("sAMAccountName", LogonName);
    }
}
```

And then just expect whatever uses your code to test before setting if youre concerned with performance.
ie

```
if(class.logonName != newName) 
     class.logonName = newName;
```

Also makes it harder to accidentally cause a stackoverflow.